# Connected Subspace lies entrirely in $X$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Hi i am reading Topology by Munkres and i have one doubt at the last line of lemma 23.2. It is written that

> Hence Y must lie entirely in C or in D.

I can't understand the above quoted statement. Everything else i was able to understand . I am attaching the screenshot where the lemma and its full proof is illustrated and i have highlighted the above statement(that i was not able to understand).The theorem's statement reads as: If the sets C and D form a separation of X, and if Y is a connected subspace of X, then Y lies entirely within either C or D.[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that $C\cap Y$ and $D\cap Y$ are nonempty, then we conclude contradiction (contradiction with fact that $Y$ is conected). So it must be case that $C\cap Y=\emptyset$ or $D\cap Y=\emptyset$. Wlog, lets say that $D\cap Y=\emptyset$. Then $Y\subset C$ because $C\cup D = X$.

Comment: How does $C\cup D = X$ imply $Y\subset C$ as in your last statement?

Comment: Because $D\cap Y=\emptyset$.